# R - Neuralnet package using dummies and quantitative variables in supervised learning

Tags: r, neural-network, dummy-variable, supervised-learning

I am using the package `neuralnet` for R and would like to use supervised learning.
In my setting I have 15 explanatory variables (8 of them are dummy variables, every dummy contains `0 and 1` as values, the other explanatory variables are real numbered).
However, I want to use all explanatory variables to predict a target vector (real numbered). 
So, my setting is a regression problem.

If I run my neural net without the dummies, the `neuralnet()`-function produces results.
However, by incorporating the dummies, I get the error message:

[image: Error Message, If Dummies Are Considered In Regression]

Obviously, the dummies cause the error. Running the function without them works fine.

How can I make the neuralnet considering the dummies properly and create an output?

Please find below a reproduceable example as well as the neural network setting:

```
#### install packages
# install.packages("devtools")
# require(devtools)

# devtools::install_github("bips-hb/neuralnet") # CRAN version contains bug, use github version
# require(neuralnet)

### create data
set.seed(1)
dt          <- matrix(rnorm(200), nrow = 200, ncol = 3)
dummy1 <- as.factor( c(rep(1,100), rep(0,100)) )                # create vector with data (1,0) for first dummy, save as factor
dummy2 <- as.factor( c(rep(0,100), rep(1,100)) )                # create vector with data (0,1) for second dummy, save as factor
dummy_df <- data.frame(dummy1, dummy2)                          # merging both dummies into dataframe
class(dummy_df[,1]) # factor
class(dummy_df[,2]) # factor

# bringing original data and dummies together
train <- cbind(as.data.frame(dt), dummy_df)

# see colnames
colnames(train)


# start neural net
nnet <- neuralnet(formula = V1 ~ V2 + V3 + dummy1 + dummy2, # use V1 as target for supervised learning
                  data = train,
                  hidden = 1,                # neurons
                  threshold = 0.01,          # termination derivative is reached         
                  rep = 5,                   # trainings
                  startweights = NULL,       # starting weights 
                  learningrate.factor = list(minus = 0.5, plus = 1.2), # increasing and decrasing factors 
                  algorithm = "rprop+",      # rprop algorithm with weight updating 
                  err.fct = "sse",           # use sum squared errors as error function 
                  act.fct = "tanh",          # use hyperbolic tangent   
                  linear.output = TRUE,      # output function is linear, regression problem 
                  lifesign = "full",         # print behavior 
                  stepmax = 200000)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Dominiks answer, of which he seems absolutely correct, incorporating the dummy variables are rather simple, either using a package like (i believe) dummmies, or the base package and `model.matrix` as shown below

```
dt          <- matrix(rnorm(200), nrow = 200, ncol = 3)
dummy1 <- as.factor( c(rep(1,100), rep(0,100)) )                # create vector with data (1,0) for first dummy, save as factor
dummy2 <- as.factor( c(rep(0,100), rep(1,100)) )                # create vector with data (0,1) for second dummy, save as factor
dummy_df <- data.frame(dummy1, dummy2)                          # merging both dummies into dataframe

mm <- model.matrix(~ dummy1 + dummy2 - 1, data = dummy_df) #-1 removes intercept.
train <- cbind(dt, mm)
neuralnet::neuralnet(V1 ~ . , data = train) #possibly adding -1 to the formula is sensible as well.
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `neuralnet` does not take factors as input (predictors). Just use the numeric values of the dummies, then it works.

```
dummy1 <- as.numeric(dummy1)
dummy2 <- as.numeric(dummy2)
dummy_df <- data.frame(dummy1, dummy2)
```

This works fine as long as you have factors with only two levels. If you have more than two levels use [dummy coding](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/dummy-coding-the-how-and-why/).